# mysql error when adding a column to an existing table

Tags: python, mysql, database-migration, pymysql

Using yo-yo migrations (pymysql underneath) I'm trying to add a column to a database as part of a migration and get an error with a stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/yoyo/migrations.py", line 311, in apply
    getattr(self.step, direction)(backend, force)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/yoyo/migrations.py", line 411, in apply
    self._execute(cursor, self._apply)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/yoyo/migrations.py", line 377, in _execute
     cursor.execute(stmt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
     result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
     conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
     self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
result.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
     first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
     packet.check_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
     err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
     raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')
```

the table is created like so:

```
steps = [
  step("""
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
    `id`              VARCHAR(36)   NOT NULL DEFAULT 'uuid',
    `name`            VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL,
    `contact_email`   VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL,
    `organisation_id` VARCHAR(36)   NOT NULL,
    `active`          BIT           NOT NULL,
    `permissions`     VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL,
    `creator_id`      VARCHAR(36)   NOT NULL,
    `modifier_id`     VARCHAR(36)   NOT NULL,
    `date_created`    DATETIME      NOT NULL,
    `date_modified`   DATETIME      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`organisation_id`) REFERENCES `organisation`(`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
  """, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`")
]
```

The migration looks like this:

```
steps = [  # pylint:disable=invalid-name
  step("""ALTER TABLE `user` ADD `phone` VARCHAR(32) NULL""", """ALTER 
  TABLE `user` DROP COLUMN `phone`""", "all"),
]
```

The ALTER runs ok when I'm connected to mySQL myself. 
I can also run a migration altering columns and thats ok. Just isn't working when run with the migration to add a new column.

Comment: Is it really the `ALTER` that causes the error to be thrown? I rather suspect the `CREATE` fails because `organisation` hasn't been created yet and therefore the foreign key constraints points to nowhere.

Comment: nope CREATE runs first and is ok, I omitted organisation table creation as I thought it was irrelevant

Comment: I think its a pymysql issue as running it directly against database the command works